# Covering of Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometry

The question consists of several parts:

1. What is the simply connected ramified covering of the Riemann sphere with  ramification indexes {2. 3. 5} over three points of RS in every preimage of these points
2. Does there exist not simply connected covering with the same properties?
3. What is the minimal degree of nontrivial ramified covering ramification indexes, which divide (what it means?) {2. 3. 5} over three points of RS in every preimage of these points?

As I know such covering is a sphere tiled with pentagons. And they satisfy 1).
But how explain the 2) and 3) I don't know.